# How can I retrieve previous value of a variable?

Tags: c#

How can I retrieve previous value of a variable? 
Considering this:

```
Int x = 0;
x = 5; 
x = 10;
```

How can retrieve both old values of x ?

Comment: You can't. If you need to remember them, you need to store them somewhere before changing the value of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I retrieve previous value of a variable?

You probably need Stack. the stack is the structure that you can add (push) and remove (pop) items only from one side.

```
Stack<int> x = new Stack<int>();
x.Push(0); // push first value
x.Push(5); // second value after first value
x.Push(10); //...
```

Now at the top of the stack you have 10. you can move backward.

```
var value = x.Pop(); // 10
var pre = x.Pop();   // 5
var prePre = x.Pop();// 0
```

Note that `Pop` will throw exception if the stack is empty. also to get the item from top of the stack without removing it you can use Peek .

```
var value = x.Peek(); // 10
var value2 = x.Peek();// still 10
```

Note that Stack uses an array internally.

Answer (score 2):

I would place them in a list.

```
var values = new List<int>();

int x = 0;
values.Add(x);
x=5;
values.Add(x);
x=10;
values.Add(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple.

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>();
iList.Add(10);
iList.Add(20);
```

...

Then you can simply get it with:

```
iList.ElementAt(0);
iList.ElementAt(1);
```

or

```
iList.Last();
iList.First();
```

or even:

```
iList.Where(x => x > 5).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define them as separate variables. int var1, int var2, etc...

Comment: Nope ,  that's not a good one. Plz let me know if a possible solution exist for the given question...

Comment: My instructor asked me that, he said that it is possible by something related to pointer... I don't know...

Comment: A pointer is only holding the adress of a value. But you want access to at least three of them. So, like the others stated, you have to keep them in a kind of storidge, a list or an array or something similar. May be, he was thinking of a pointer to an array of values?

Comment: @AmirMahdiHosseini Your instructor is wrong, there's no way to 'undo' changes to a variable. You need to store the previous values somewhere, like kevindeleon suggested, or use a collection as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot keep track of a variable once the value has been reassigned. You will have to create more variables. Something like this:

```
var x = 0;
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 10;
```

Depending on your logic, assign or grab the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the general properties of your local variables and fields. There is no difference for value types and reference types. Your variable contains their value (or pointer to the value on heap).

When you use assignment operator "=" you are actually replace value on your variable. For [value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) you can't get previous variable because each assignment creates new variable. For [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) assignment just replace pointer to the value, then your old value can be retrieved if you'll save pointer to 'em.

There are special cases with [boxing and unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer to your question is quite simple: you can save previous value before new assigment. The answers above implements the simpliest way with new variables:

```
var x = 0;
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 10;
```

If you do not know how many assignments will you have in your code you can implement the simplest history collection.

```
List<int> xHistoy = new List<int>(); // Or Queue<int>
int x;
private int AssignWithHistory(int val)
{
    xHistory.Add(val);
    return x;
}

x = AssignWithHistory(0);
x = AssignWithHistory(5);
x = AssignWithHistory(10);
```

But I think that the main goal is not to implement your scenario but to understand the principle of the variables and their storage in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
    private int _x;

    private int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;

            if (XHistory == null)
            {
                XHistory = new List<int> {_x};
            }
            else
            {
                XHistory.Insert(0, _x);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<int> XHistory { get; set; }

    private void ShowHistoryOfX() => XHistory?.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Every time you assign a value to X it will add to a history list, which you can then print out. The most recent change would be inserted at the start of the list.